# Show JSON data in table in selectbox

Tags: javascript, json, html-table, drop-down-menu

There is a JSON data and I have displayed each key value as a column in the table.
I want to export data from JSON to each column as a selectbox.
i.e. I want to show all corresponding values ​​of "country" in JSON as selectbox in COUNTRY column.

**My JSON data**

```
"kitap": [
  {
    "author": "Chinua Achebe",
    "country": "Nigeria",
    "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    "pages": 209,
    "title": "Things Fall Apart",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
    "country": "Denmark",
    "imageLink": "images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    "language": "Danish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    "pages": 784,
    "title": "Fairy tales",
    "year": 1836
  },
```

**My Javascript**

```
let table2 = document.getElementById("tr2")

var books = fetch("kitap.json")
.then(res=> res.json())
.then(veri => {for(let data in veri ) {
    for(deger of veri[data]) {

        select.innerHTML+= `
         <td><option value="${deger.author}">${deger.author}</option></td>
          <td><option value="${deger.country}">${deger.country}</option></td>
        `
    }
}})
```

How can i edit?

Comment: let select = document.getElementById("select")   ===> i have this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? A loop over the keys, then a loop for all the items for each key. Finally after aggregating into array, we do a `<select>` element using a simple utility function.

```js
var obj = {"kitap":[{"author":"Chinua Achebe","country":"Nigeria","imageLink":"images\/things-fall-apart.jpg","language":"English","link":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Things_Fall_Apart\n","pages":209,"title":"Things Fall Apart","year":1958},{"author":"Hans Christian Andersen","country":"Denmark","imageLink":"images\/fairy-tales.jpg","language":"Danish","link":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n","pages":784,"title":"Fairy tales","year":1836}]}


function do_select(select, options, name) {
  select.innerHTML = '<option>Choose ' + name + '</options>';
  options.forEach(function(value) {
    var z = document.createElement("option");
    z.setAttribute("value", value);
    z.innerText = value;
    select.appendChild(z)
  })
}

do_obj_selects(obj)

function do_obj_selects(obj) {

  var arr = obj.kitap;
  var keys = Object.keys(obj.kitap[0]);
  var result = {}
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    obj.kitap.forEach(function(item) {
      result[key] = result[key] || []
      result[key].push(item[key])
    })

    var sel_category = document.createElement("SELECT");
    sel_category.setAttribute("id", "category");
    document.body.appendChild(sel_category);
    do_select(sel_category, result[key], key)
  })
}
```

Comment: If someday you will need hierarchical dropdowns (like a tree)  you can check out my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292498/3807365)

Comment: yes I did, you've been very helpful. I will adapt it to the table by making only minor adjustments.

Comment: how do i include this externally without using var obj the json data

Comment: Get to a point (after fetch or $.ajax) where you have the `json` at hand. Then parse it into an object `obj` and continue with `do_obj_selects(obj)`