# How to implement a Nested list with multi-selection

Tags: html, css

Currently there is the following list implementation:

```html
<select id='optSelect' multiple>
  <optgroup label='Option1'>
    <option value='Option1' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option1</option>
    <option value='Option12' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option12</option>
    <option value='Option13' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option13</option>
  </optgroup>
                            
  <optgroup label='Option2'>
    <option value='Option21' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option21</option>
    <option value='Option22' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option22</option>
    <option value='Option23' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option23</option>
  </optgroup>
                            
  <optgroup label='Option3'>
    <option value='Option31' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option31</option>
    <option value='Option32' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option32</option>
    <option value='Option33' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option33</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

It is necessary to implement it so that when hovering over, for example, the Option2 element on the right at the Option2 level, a list of elements with:

```
<option value='Option21' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option21</option>
<option value='Option22' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option22</option>
<option value='Option23' style='font-size: 15px;'>Option23</option>
```

How to implement it? Help please!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sleSz.png)

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292498/3807365

Comment: I need the second select not to be visible at first.  So that it becomes visible when one of the options in optgroup label='Option1 is already selected

Comment: but in the example i wrote, it only populates the select as soon as the previous one is selected. isn't that almost the same?

Comment: No, it should be hidden and appear when the option is selected in the first one. And it should be in the form of a set of options, not a separate list.

Comment: optgroup label is not interactive. though you can get the same effect using only option tags and css. please show the select before and after clicking (hovering?) the `Option2` element

Comment: Added the image to the question as it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sleSz.png

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /* Style the select element */
> #optSelect {
>   width: 300px;
>   height: 200px;
> }
>
> /* Style the option groups */
> optgroup {
>   font-weight: bold;
>   font-size: 20px;
>   padding: 5px;
> }
>
> /* Style the options */
> option {
>   padding: 5px;
> }   </style> </head> <body>
> ```
>
> Option 1.1
>       Option 1.2
>       Option 1.3
>
> ```
> <!-- Define the second option group -->
> <optgroup label='Option2'>
>   <option value='Option21'>Option 2.1</option>
>   <option value='Option22'>Option 2.2</option>
>   <option value='Option23'>Option 2.3</option>
> </optgroup>
>
> <!-- Define the third option group -->
> <optgroup label='Option3'>
>   <option value='Option31'>Option 3.1</option>
>   <option value='Option32'>Option 3.2</option>
>   <option value='Option33'>Option 3.3</option>
> </optgroup>
> ```